# Generic jQuery callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to have a callback on a jQuery object that doesn't do anything else. something like:

```
$("div", this).do(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

The only way I know how to do that is:

```
var obj = $("div", this);
$(obj).hide();
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method

```
$("div", this).each(function(){
    // perform some function on each element in the set
    $(this).hide();
});
```

This is useful if you need to run some custom code on each element in the jQuery object.

If all you need is to call another jQuery method like `.hide()`, then you don't need `.each()`. Most jQuery methods will operate on all elements in the set automatically. They call this *"implicit iteration"*.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to write

```
$(this).find("div").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but what you're probably looking for is the each function

```
$('div', this).each(function(){
  //do something with all the divs inside this
});
```